# Facebook PHP SDK giving an error

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to run the example that comes with Facebook's PHP SDK, however I'm getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException:
>   60: SSL certificate problem, verify
>   that the CA cert is OK. Details:
>   error:14090086:SSL
>   routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate
>   verify failed thrown in
>   C:\wamp\www\fb\src\facebook.php on
>   line 614

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem is cURL has not been configured to trust the server's HTTPS certificate, you can fix that by adding this line of code:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Comment: This was very helpful, especially to those testing Facebook apps locally! To make this work, I had to actually add $opts[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false; in base_facebook.php around line 935, before curl_setopt_array($ch, $opts);

Comment: @BryanGentry is it advisable to remove that line of code once my site goes into production?

Comment: I would recommend removing it for live production apps.

Comment: You probably don't want to disable SSL verification. The root cause is that Facebook updated their SSL certificate and the root isn't available. The [FB SDK on github](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/master/src/fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt) contains updated root certificates

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same problem, and disabling peer verification is not acceptable in my case.
I updated the fa_ca_chain_bundle.crt file (from [facebook's gitbub](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/tree/master/src)) and it works now.

Regards,
Marek

Comment: I agree. Disabling SSL verification is a terrible idea.

Comment: Can you tell me where you put the crt file after you've downloaded it, so that it works?

Answer (score 3):

Raymond Ho answer of adding this line of code works fine:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Just make sure for the new facebook sdk to have it in the "Facebook_base" file before:

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

find this line

and immediately following it, add:

$opts[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;

Answer (score 1):

other way is add this line, is the same suggestion as the others replies, but in one line, make sure to include the Facebook SDK first

```
Facebook::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem, and you just need to update the crt file that you can find here
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/master/src/fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt

the crt file is inside the same folder of the file that gives you that error

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo In this case its an encrypted .crt file that's needed to fix this issue, he can't really share it other than linking to it somewhere externally, and the link he gave is from facebook's official sdk, its unlikely to go down