# Facebook ssl certification error

Tags: php, facebook, oauth

As they mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444006/facebook-php-sdk-giving-an-error?answertab=votes#tab-top) i add the line in base_facebook.php
  after that it throwed this exception   **OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user** 
 thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide some code

Comment: if you are not using Outh 2.0 ,After a certain amount of time, your access token expires.

To prevent this, you can request the 'offline_access' permission during the authentication

Comment: offlice_access permission is depreciated.

Comment: Thanks guys . I added $user instead of me in $Facebook->api('me'); after doing that i worked fine . But when i click logout with redirect page . It is not actually getting logout from Facebook . It is just redirecting to the page. If i did without redirect days. Working fine. But no use of it. Help with guys.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue lately and what I did is changed SSL variables in base_facebook.php

Try following settings.

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2
```